# Google limit usage

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-oauth, google-console-developer

The following questions are about google API credentials
(In my case - maps and calendars API's)

1. Where can I see my usages analytics of google API?
   (On the developer dashboard, I found only the past 30 days range,
   without any details about summary or total calls per their limits)
2. Where can I see the limit of each google API? (I found 10 different answers for the limits)

Thanks!

"The only source of knowledge is experience." -Albert Einstein

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For calendar, here is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/pricing) to know the usage limits.

> The Google Calendar API has a courtesy limit of 1,000,000 queries per
>   day.
>
> To view or change usage limits for your project, or to request an
>   increase to your quota, [open the API Library](https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/apiui/apis/library) in the Developers
>   Console.
>
> If you have [enabled billing](https://developers.google.com/console/help/console/#billing) for your project, you can see the
>   quota percentage for each API. You can view and change quotas from the
>   API section's **API Library** and **Enabled APIs** links. Selecting an
>   API from the API Library list or from the Enabled APIs page takes you
>   to a page with overview, usage, and quota links for that API. Choosing
>   Quotas lets you view and change quota-related settings. Choosing Usage
>   provides you with usage statistics as well as response code and method
>   information.

And for maps, you can visit this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage).

> **Standard Usage Limits**
>
> Users of the standard API:
>
> - Free until exceeding 25,000 map loads per 24 hours
>
> *Note: Quota exceptions may apply. [Learn more here](https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/standard-plan-2016-update.html).*
>
> Enable pay-as-you-go billing to unlock higher quotas:
>
> After exceeding the free usage limits, billing at $0.50 USD / 1000
>   additional requests, up to 100,000 per 24 hours.